# In my app when I open an activity and then destroy it, I take memory info using dumpsys meminfo command, After every cycle number of views increase

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

1st cycle

App Summary

```
                   Pss(KB)                        Rss(KB)

                    ------                         ------

       Java Heap:     4844                          38296

     Native Heap:     5392                           8684

            Code:      128                         107648

           Stack:      656                            972

        Graphics:     8036                           8040

   Private Other:     6520

          System:    35205

         Unknown:                                    8400



       TOTAL PSS:    60781            TOTAL RSS:   172040       TOTAL SWAP PSS:    31105
```

Objects

```
           Views:      457         ViewRootImpl:        2

     AppContexts:       14           Activities:        2

          Assets:       28        AssetManagers:        0

   Local Binders:       82        Proxy Binders:       99

   Parcel memory:       47         Parcel count:      130

Death Recipients:        1             WebViews:        1
```

after 104 cycle:

App Summary

```
                   Pss(KB)                        Rss(KB)

                    ------                         ------

       Java Heap:     4260                          35820

     Native Heap:     6232                           8648

            Code:      336                          98472

           Stack:      560                            740

        Graphics:     8148                           8152

   Private Other:     7204

          System:   213197

         Unknown:                                    7280



       TOTAL PSS:   239937            TOTAL RSS:   159112       TOTAL SWAP PSS:   209472
```

Objects

```
           Views:     8547         ViewRootImpl:        2

     AppContexts:      223           Activities:      105

          Assets:       28        AssetManagers:        0

   Local Binders:      185        Proxy Binders:      407

   Parcel memory:      638         Parcel count:      342

Death Recipients:        2             WebViews:      104
```

How can I figure out what views are increasing in every cycle, is there any tool in android studio or something.
I am new here, please be kind.

I tried to check android studio profiler if I can get any clue, but cannot find.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler
Capture a heap dump and load it into the profiler